# Can I make a cake with finely ground coffee instead of cocoa powder?

Tags: substitutions, cake, coffee

I used all my cocoa powder. Will it taste good if I use coffee instead? If anyone has done this before, please share your experiences and hints.

Comment: I would brew strong coffee and use that instead of powered coffee.

Answer (score 5):

Coffee cake is good, but it's better to start from a recipe for coffee cake than try to adapt a chocolate cake.  Cocoa powder brings an appreciable amount of fat and bulk to the recipe.

You need to be very careful about terminology.  *Coffee powder* in many places refers to powdered instant (soluble) coffee, which isn't the best coffee drink but is very suiatable as a flvouring.  It should be dissolved in liquid before adding tot he cake mix (following the recipe).  I have seen *coffee powder* used to refer to finely ground coffee beans.  It's not unknown to add these to food, but it's not common.  We [discussed this recently](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/93920/20413).

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.But dont expect it to be a chocolate cake.

Also the quantity of coffee must be 1/6 th the amount of cocoa powder you would have used for chocolate cake.

Otherwise your cake will definitely turn bitter.

Cocoa and Coffee are altogether different material. These are not substitutes. You can try with cocoa powder, Coffee powder(try with instant ) and mix cocoa powder and coffee. You will get three different flavor profile.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Note: the asker is talking about ground coffee, not instant coffee.

Answer (score 4):

Potentially, but using ground coffee as an ingredient often doesn't work that well as it can add a gritty texture and excessive bitterness.

Bear in in mind that when you make coffee to drink the process   generally involves a carefully controlled brewing time and separating the ground from the liquor and even if you make 'cowboy coffee' you avoid drinking the grounds.

Instant coffee is better direct substitute for cocoa powder or alternatively you can brew some coffee and add it as a liquid ingredient, although this may require adjusting the recipe a bit so you don't end up with too much liquid in the mixture.